# Cannot get a user via Windows Authentication: "A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated."

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, windows-authentication

I use the following code to get a users name in C#. It works perfectly fine on my computer, but as soon as I deploy it to a server it breaks with the error message: *"A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated."*

```
private bool isUserAuthenticated()
{
    return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
}

private string getUserName()
{
    return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
}
```

My web.config file (excerpt):

```
<system.web>
     <authentication mode="Windows" />
</system.web>
```

I then proceeded and enabled Windows Authentication for the website on IIS.

[image: Screenshot of my IIS authentication screen]

Did I miss something? What could be the error here and how can I fix it? Any thoughts are highly appreciated. If you need more information please leave a comment.

Comment: What are you using to connect from a client perspective?

Comment: @AllanElder Internet Explorer. A small window pops up where I can enter my Windows credentials, if entered correctly it displays the said error message.

Answer (score 0):

try the below mentioned work around:

1. On the Management Server, click Start, click Run, type gpedit.msc, and then click OK.
2. Under Computer Configuration, expand Windows Settings, expand Security Settings, expand Local Policies, and then expand Security Options.
3. In the Policy pane, right-click Network access: Do not allow storage of credentials or .NET Passports for network authentication, click Properties, click Disabled, and then click OK.

Comment: Checkout below link may be helpful  http://bartwullems.blogspot.in/2012/08/iis-manager-error-specified-logon.html

Answer (score 0):

When you are prompted to enter the Windows credentials you should use:

servername\username 
password

instead of:

username
password

Comment: What's the difference between these two inputs? Will the authentication process behaves differently?